# What is the exact meaning of から in this sentence?

Tags: particle-から

I know the sentence

> 大丈夫 みんな支えてくれるから。

means "Don’t worry. Everyone’s supporting you.", but I don't know the exact meaning and function of から in this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That から is 'because'.

There are actually two sentences here: 大丈夫。and みんな支えてくれるから。

The normal single sentence form would be みんな支えてくれるから大丈夫 "everyone is supporting you so it's okay". But in your scenario, the person says it will be okay and then goes on to clarify why it will be okay.

Comment: thank you very much